# Standard UITableViewCell overlaps my Custom Cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Here what I've done : I made a big custom cell in nib that is much bigger than standard cell and has a blue background.

Here it is, CommonListViewCell.xib

[image]

Here's a screenshot that it's connected to a proper class :

[image]

Here is this class :

```
import UIKit

class CommonListViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var background: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
    override func awakeFromNib() {

        super.awakeFromNib()
        titleLabel.font = UIFont(name: "roboto", size: titleLabel.font.pointSize)
        NSLog("CommonListViewCell font changed")
    }    
}
```

And here's my ViewController that has this TableView :

```
import UIKit

class CommonListFragment: BaseFragment,UIScrollViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet var lvMain: UITableView!



    var prayerList = [PrayerDescription]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.lvMain.delegate = self;
         self.lvMain.dataSource = self;
         self.lvMain.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "CommonListViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "commonlistidentifier")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

     convenience init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle? , listType type:Int) {
        self.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        switch type{
        case A.PRAYERS_TO_SAINTS:
            prayerList = PrayerDescriptionEngine.saints
            break
        case A.CANNONS_AND_ACATHISTS:
            prayerList = PrayerDescriptionEngine.acathistsAndCannons
            break
        default :
            prayerList = PrayerDescriptionEngine.allPurpose
            break
        }
    }

    override func nightCheck() {
        Utils.nightCheck([lvMain])
        lvMain.reloadData()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{

        return prayerList.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("commonlistidentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommonListViewCell

        // Configure the cell...
        cell.textLabel?.text = prayerList[indexPath.row].name
        setLabelFont(cell.textLabel!)
        Utils.nightCheck([cell.textLabel!])
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        parentVC.immedeateClose()
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
                   didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
        parentVC.showActions(false)
        NSLog("You selected cell #\(prayerList[ indexPath.row].resId)!")
        let vc = AllPrayer(nibName :"AllPrayer", bundle: nil)
        _=PrayerDescriptionEngine()
        vc.setResId(prayerList[ indexPath.row].resId)
        self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: false)
    }



}
```

And here is the ugly result :

[image]

So, my custom table cell is obviously behind standard cell. By some reason, standard cell has the data filled right, and custom cell on the back has "Label" text on it. And custom cell is not the size I specified.

So, please, help me with this one - I need my custom cell to be the only one in TableView, having my color and my size I specified in xib

Comment: You're setting all your data on the cell's `textLabel` which is a label created by the `UITableViewCell` base class.  Your label is called `titleLabel` so you should be using that one.

Comment: @dan thank you ! but the size of the cell is still not mine, it is still standard size

Comment: @user2976267 the size of your cell is different because you haven't changed in your `tableView` in the `Interface Builder`. Your `tableView` is using the default cell size of `44pt`. You need to change it in the `Size Inspector` tab in Xcode's right panel. And if you want that the size of your be as per the length of the text then you must implement `heightForRowAtIndexPath` method.

Answer (score 1):

In `tablviewdelegate` method, you r accessing **cell.textlabel** of current tableview while you have to access **cell.titlelabel** of your custom cell. And you are setting background color of cell, thats why it overlapping it.

You have to access properties of custom cell not of current cell.
So,

Replace `cell.textlabel`  with `cell.titlelabel`

And as you r loading custom cell remove prototype cell of tableview in storyboard if you have one.

Hope this will work

Answer (score 0):

Is your table view in storyborad? 
Select your tableview cell and in the identity inspector make recognise the custom cell class.

[image]